# Can we pass arguments to a coffeescript-class?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, arguments, anonymous-function, iife

Is it somehow possible to pass some `arguments` into the coffeescript-class `iife`?

A CoffeeScript class-instance like this:

```
class App
```

results normally in this:

```
App = (function() {

  function App() {}

  return App;

})();
```

However, maybe there's a way to populate the anonymous-wrapper with some arguments, like this:

```
App = (function($) {

  function App() {}

  return App;

})(jQuery);
```

Currently I wrap each module in an *superfluous* extra wrapper:

```
(($) ->
  class App
)(jQuery)
```

But I find this definitely not beautiful (like coffescript usually is).

Comment: The thing is Coffeescript passes the `_super` parameter in that closure when needed so I doubt there's a way to do it other than what you're doing now.

Comment: Also you can make it pretty: `do (doc = document) ->`

Comment: @elclanrs `do (doc = document) ->` works only if the argument is the same as the thing in the iife-*caller*. Sorry my fault, updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think elclanrs's comment is the answer you are looking for.

In coffeescript `do ($) ->` will compile to `(function($){ … })($)`.

But `do ($ = jQuery) ->` will compile to `(function($){ … })(jQuery)`.

There really isn't any cleaner way of doing it than this. It's one line at the top of the file and makes it very clear what you are doing.

```
do ($ = jQuery) ->
  class App
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
class A extends GenericClass("some_parameter")
```

where GenericClass is defined as

```
GenericClass = (params) ->
    return { some: objects }
```

Honestly I wouldnt do that as it totally makes it intransparent what you try to do.
Maybe you can explain what you try to do in terms of features/business value and not so much in terms of CoffeeScript syntax?

Comment: Nice workaround! However, this seems not really coffeeish to me ;)

Comment: hmm, dunno! As long as I dont understand what exactly you try to accomplish its hard to say if its more or less coffeeish. in General if you try to inject some piece of code i'd try to use some class method calls